# Appending an input to a form AND a rendered element

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form whose elements are formatted neatly in a table that's nested within the form tags, and I want to add another row to that table with a new input. How can I append that new input to both the form element (so that it's present in document.forms.formName and will submit with the form) AND to the new row's cell (so that it's rendered inside the row)?

Calling the appendChild method on the cell and the form element both just appends it to the last one called, rather than giving it a kind of dual membership. Is there some sort of append I can call from the form that doesn't interfere with how the element is rendered?

Edit: Woops, had the form nested inside the table, not vice versa. This doesn't work in Firefox 3.6 but does work in Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: For simplicity, I would suggest jQuery, since different browsers handle `table` manipulation differently. (And, of course, consider not using `table`'s for layout.) And if your `form` encapsulates your `table`, you only need to add a new row to your `table` for it to join the `form`.

Comment: Ah, actually I had the form nested inside the table, not the other way around. A quick test reveals that this causes the input to fail to be registered in the form under Firefox 3.6 (although not under IE8). Guess that's what I get for failing to take a closer look at my old code.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not going to guess how the `FORM` tag was in the `TABLE`, but if you had multiple rows, you're entirely up to the browser's quirks mode rendering of your form and table.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a copy of an existing table row, just clone the entire row and add it to the table. If the table is in a form, the input will automatically be added to the form.

A trivial example:

```
<form ...>
  <table> 
    <tr><td><input name="foo">
  </table>
</form>

<button onclick="
  var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
  var tBody = table.tBodies[0]
  var newRow = tBody.rows[0].cloneNode(true);
  tBody.appendChild(newRow);
">Add a row</button>
```

Note that you will probably need to update the input's name and value and do some other tidying up, the above just shows the strategy.